# tcp-client на ассемблере под x64 linux

Tags: linux, tcp, yasm

Код tcp-client'а использует системные вызовы `sendmsg (rax/46, rdi/int fd, rsi/struct msghdr *msg, rdx/unsigned flags)` и `recvmsg (rax/47, rdi/int fd, rsi/struct msghdr *msg, rdx/unsigned int flags)`

```
        ;; yasm -g dwarf2 -f elf64 -a x86 message.asm -o msg.o
        ;; ld -o msg msg.o

    segment .bss

listen_socket: resq 1

    segment .data

packet istruc message
    at message.length_mes,          dw  0x2800
        at message.message_id,          dw  0x0100
        at message.scheme_id,           dw  0x0100
        at message.version,     dw  0x0100
        at message.timestamp,           dq  0
        at message.keeepaliveinterval,  dd  0xe8030000
        at message.credentials,         dq  0
        at message.ext,             dw  0
iend
;packet_len             equ $ - packet ;

pop_sa istruc sockaddr_in
        at sockaddr_in.sin_family,  dw 2             ; AF_INET
        at sockaddr_in.sin_port,    dw 0x2823        ; port 9000
        at sockaddr_in.sin_addr,    dd 0xf4e8d05b    ; 91.208.232.244
        at sockaddr_in.sin_zero,    dd 0, 0
iend
sockaddr_in_len     equ $ - pop_sa

timeval: ;struct
        tv_sec  dq 0
        tv_usec dq 0

buffer      times 512 db 0x0

    segment .text
    global _start

_start:

struc message
    .length_mes             resw 1
    .message_id             resw 1
    .scheme_id              resw 1
    .version                resw 1
    .timestamp              resq 1
    .keeepaliveinterval         resd 1
    .credentials            resq 2
    .ext                    resw 1
endstruc

struc sockaddr_in
    .sin_family resw 1
    .sin_port   resw 1
    .sin_addr   resd 1
    .sin_zero   resb 8
endstruc

    mov rsi, timeval    ;   struct timespec *tp
    mov rdi, 0      ;   const clockid_t which_clock - CLOCK_REALTIME
    mov rax, 228        ;   SYS_CLOCK_GETTIME
    syscall
    mov r8, qword [tv_sec]
    mov r9, qword [tv_usec]
    imul r8, 1000000000
    sub r8, r9
    mov qword [packet + message.timestamp], r8

    mov rdi, 2      ; AF_INET
    mov rsi, 1      ; SOCK_STREAM
    mov rdx, 6      ; PROTO_TCP
    mov rax, 41     ; SYS_SOCKET
    syscall

    cmp rax, 0
    jl exit
    mov [listen_socket], rax

    mov rsi, pop_sa     ;
    mov rdx, sockaddr_in_len    ;
    mov rdi, [listen_socket]
    mov rax, 42     ; SYS_CONNECT
    syscall

    cmp rax, 0
    jl exit

    xor rdx, rdx
    mov rsi, packet
    mov rdi, [listen_socket]
    mov rax, 46     ; SYS_SENDMSG
    syscall

    xor rdx, rdx
    mov rsi, buffer
    mov rdi, [listen_socket]
    mov rax, 47     ; SYS_RECVMSG
    syscall

exit:   
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rax, 60     ;   SYS_EXIT
    syscall
```

системный вызов sendmsg завершается с ошибкой -14, как исправить ее? Или использовать sendto/recvto, но там никаких реакции нет.

Comment: какой у send номер системного вызова на ассемблере?

Comment: не знаю. посмотрите libc. хотя судя по man это почти то же, что sendto, но при использовании sendto dstaddr и addrlen надо передавать NULL. так же можно использовать обычный write, если не надо передавать какие то специализированные флаги

Comment: учитывая что возвращается ошибка 14, bad_address подозреваю, что вы для параметра dstaddr передаете не NULL, а видимо грязь, потому что я не вижу в вашем коде я не виду где бы он мог передаваться, если конечно он не в rdx

Comment: send нет. В sendto при передачи в rdx NULL, ошибок не выдает, но и соединения то же нет.

Comment: что значит соединения нет. соединение же при connect происходит, если он ошибок не вернул то вероятно оно есть

Comment: Если запустить код, то в wireshark нет информации об отправке и получении пакетов, к тому же в recvto вовращается 0.

Comment: попробовал ваш код с 44 вызовом и передачей обычного текста, tcpdump отлично видит соединение и передаваемый текст. на счет sendmsg не знаю. И да, программа ждет получения данных на recvmsg

Comment: sendto и recvto выглядит более оптимистично чем sendmsg и recvmsg, но получить ответ пока не получается.

Comment: @Mike вы можете написать изменения, которые вы внесли чтобы код подал признаки жизни?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Cxqt5fs0 там ip и порт только мои. а изменения буквально номер вызова 44 и передаю ему строку msg, что бы в дампе пакетов ее было сразу видно

Comment: спасибо 2 @Mike

Comment: Есть ли какие-либо тонкости при настройки tcp-сокета для работы по vpn?

Comment: нет, ему фиолетово как ОС будет передавать пакеты. это уже на уроне ядра решается через какой интерфейс пойдет пакет и как его оформлять для канального уровня

Comment: все не так просто, connect() - блокирующий вызов, поэтому до него сокет необходимо сделать не блокируемым со всеми вытекающими проверками

Comment: Ну делайте, это никак не зависит от vpn. И не имеет ни какого отношения к заданному верху вопросу